# Element-wise addition on tuple or list python

Tags: python, tuples

I was wondering if anyone can teach me how to do element wise addition on a tuple or list without using zip, numpy arrays, or any of those modules?

For example if I have:

```
a = (1,0,0,1)
b = (2,1,0,1)
```

how can i get: `(3,1,0,2)` instead of `(1,0,0,1,2,1,0,1)` ?

Comment: Why do you not want to use `zip`?  `tuple(map(sum, zip(a, b)))` seems like the obvious solution here, and it works for more than two inputs.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `operator.add`

```
from operator import add
>>>map(add, a, b)
[3, 1, 0, 2]
```

In `python3`

```
>>>list(map(add, a, b))
```

Comment: And you can use `tuple(map(add, a, b))` if you want as a tuple

Answer (score 1):

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are really useful:

```
[a[i] + b[i] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by simply iterating over the length of list(assuming both the lists have equal length) and adding up the values at that indices in both the lists.

```
a = (1,0,0,1)
b = (2,1,0,1)
c = (1,3,5,7)
#You can add more lists as well
n = len(a)
#if length of lists is not equal then we can use:
n = min(len(a), len(b), len(c))
#As this would not lead to IndexError
sums = []
for i in xrange(n):
    sums.append(a[i] + b[i] + c[i]) 

print sums
```

Comment: what if they're not the same length and if its more than just two lists :S sorry I'm really new at this and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function, see here: 
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools

```
map(func, seq)
```

For example:

```
a,b=(1,0,0,1),(2,1,0,1)
c = map(lambda x,y: x+y,a,b)
print c
```

Answer (score 0):

This will save you if the length of both lists are not the same:

```
result = [a[i] + b[i] for i in range(min(len(a), len(b))]
```

Comment: what if there's more than 2 lists? :S sorry I'm really new at this

Comment: Then you can go for something like this:

result = [a[i] + b[i] + c[i] for i in range(min(min(len(a), len(b)), len(c)))]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works well for deep as well as shallow nested lists or tuples

```
import operator
        def list_recur(l1, l2, op = operator.add):
            if not l1:
                return type(l1)([])
            elif isinstance(l1[0], type(l1)):
                return type(l1)([list_recur(l1[0], l2[0], op)]) + \
list_recur(l1[1:],l2[1:], op)
            else:
                return type(l1)([op(l1[0], l2[0])]) + \
list_recur(l1[1:], l2[1:], op)
```

It (*by default*) performs element wise addition, but you can specify more complex functions and/or lambdas (provided they are binary)

Answer (score 0):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in combination with [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> tuple(x+y for x,y in zip(a,b))
(3, 1, 0, 2)
```